# Covariance greater than Variance?

Tags: correlation, variance, standard-deviation, covariance

It is straightforward to verify that for two random variables $X$ and $Y$ with variances $\sigma^2_X \neq \sigma^2_Y$, we have that

$$\Big|{\rm Cov}(X, Y)\Big| \leq \max\{\sigma^2_X,\, \sigma^2_Y\}$$

On the other hand, is is *not* true in general that $\Big|{\rm Cov}(X, Y)\Big| \leq \min\{\sigma^2_X,\, \sigma^2_Y\}$

Assume $\sigma^2_X$ is the smaller variance. Then if we have

$$\sigma^2_X \leq \Big|{\rm Cov}(X, Y)\Big|  \leq \sigma^2_Y \Rightarrow \sigma^2_X \leq |\rho| \sigma_X  \sigma_Y \Rightarrow \frac {\sigma_X}{\sigma_Y}\leq |\rho|$$

Theoretically, this is perfectly feasible, the bi-variate normal case being the easiest example. But somehow it doesn't feel very "likely in practice", *when $X$ and $Y$ are measured in the same units*, to observe the ratio of standard deviations being smaller than the (absolute) correlation coefficient -but I may be wrong.

**So I am looking for any kind of real-world-data-sets experience on such a phenomenon, in an attempt to *informally* assess whether it can be considered "likely to observe in practice" or not.**

This relates to research in the following way: I am planning to use an approximating function which is piecewise, taking different functional forms depending on whether the argument of the approximated function is negative or not (which in turns depends on the above relations). And I need to obtain *theoretical* results prior to any empirical implementation, so it is not just a matter of "letting the data speak". Moreover this is not tied to any specific "part of the real world". In the interests of economy, it would be good to do all the theoretical work based on one hypothesis rather than derive all different scenarios from the beginning. And then it would be better if this hypothesis could be said to be the one "expected to hold" (informally).

Comment: I am voting to close this question on the grounds that the answers will be primarily opinion-based, though "too broad" or "unclear what you are asking" are also applicable grounds. Indeed, _how_ will the OP use any answers?  "3 out of 4 responders on stats.SE said that 5 out of 6 real-world data sets that they had occasion to examine had this property and so I expect that the data set that we are working on also enjoys this property." ??

Comment: @DilipSarwate How can communicating specific experience be not opinion-based? As to "how the OP will benefit from the answers?", he will gather a first instance of evidence on whether a theoretically possible relation actually manifests in practice. What's wrong or unscientific with that?

Comment: Alecos, you are asking if someone has seen any _actual_ data sets where $$\Big|{\rm Cov}(X, Y)\Big| \leq \min\{\sigma^2_X,\, \sigma^2_Y\}\tag{1}$$  It is entirely possible that practicing consulting statisticians (to which set I do not belong) have **not** encountered data sets of this type because if $X$ and $Y$ are uncorrelated (or have small correlation), then the experimentalists simply went on try something else and did not even bother to consult a statistician to see if something publishable could be salvaged from the data. (continued)

Comment: (Continuation) It is also possible that practicing consulting statisticians have seen _many_ data sets of this type because what the experimentalists were trying to prove _is_ that $X$ and $Y$ are uncorrelated, and now that they have data to support this hypothesis, they are consulting the statistician to publish this data in a manner that will withstand refutation. Either way, I fail to see how the information you are trying to collect is useful. 3 out of 4 dentists do recommend sugarless chewing gum, don't they? How does knowing this help?

Comment: @DilipSarwate Since you are not a practicing statistician, why are you trying a priori to exclude the possibility that they have something to say on the matter? The fact that _you_ think that they won't have to say something, or something useful, just tells us that you wouldn't ask this question -and you didn't, I did.

Comment: (Is there a reason to exclude the case $\sigma_X=\sigma_Y$?) As to whether the thread should remain open, I think that by ignoring the stuff about "informally" and "expected to hold" (which is vague and seems to ask for opinions) we could construe the question as asking for bivariate datasets exhibiting certain relationships among their variances and correlations. That does look like a perfectly clear question, albeit not one with any unique or best answer. I will therefore give the thread CW status and leave it to the community to vote to close it or leave it open.

Comment: @whuber No, but in such a case we have immediately that$|Cov| = |\rho| \sigma^2 \leq \sigma^2$, always.

Answer (score 7):

I am not quite sure what the question is asking.

The absolute value of $\operatorname{cov}(X,Y)$, the covariance of $X$ and $Y$
is no larger than $\sigma_X\sigma_Y$ which is the *geometric mean*
of the variances of $X$ and $Y$. 
Since
$$\min\{\sigma^2_X,\, \sigma^2_Y\} \leq \sigma_X\sigma_Y 
\leq \max\{\sigma^2_X,\, \sigma^2_Y\},$$
it is certainly possible for the covariance to exceed
$\min\{\sigma^2_X,\, \sigma^2_Y\}$.  In other words, the question

> Is it *not* true in general that $\big|\operatorname{cov}(X, Y)\big| \leq \min\{\sigma^2_X,\, \sigma^2_Y\}$?

has the answer that the desired relationship is not always feasible.

Consider, for example,
$X$ and $Y$ having variances $6^2$ and $8^2$ respectively.

- Suppose that the correlation coefficient $\rho$ is $\displaystyle \frac 56$.
  Then, 
  $\displaystyle\operatorname{cov}(X, Y) = \rho\sigma_X\sigma_Y = \frac 56 \times 6 \times 8
  = 40 > \min \{\sigma^2_X,\, \sigma^2_Y\} = 36,$ and
  $\displaystyle \frac{\sigma_X}{\sigma_Y} = \frac{6}{8}
  < \rho = \frac 56.$
- With a smaller correlation coefficient $\displaystyle \frac 34$,
  we have that the covariance is $36$, same as $\sigma_X^2$,
  and of course $\displaystyle \frac{\sigma_X}{\sigma_Y} = \frac{6}{8}
  = \rho$.
- If $\rho$ were even smaller, say $\displaystyle\rho = \frac 12$, the
  covariance is $24$ which is smaller than $\sigma_X^2$.

So it would appear that the OP is asking whether most real-life
data sets that people have encountered (with $\sigma_X < \sigma_Y$)
happen to have correlation coefficients that do not
exceed $\displaystyle\frac{\sigma_X}{\sigma_Y}$ in magnitude.

Comment: In the middle of my question I write (the phrase in bold letters) that I am looking for "real-world data sets experience" relate to the issue. I thought it would be clear that this would be understood to mean "is this theoretical possibility actually observed?", but apparently it was not... Thanks for bringing in the geometric mean aspect.

Answer (score 6):

Unless I've made some mistake (which I may have, I'm not clear-headed right now):

$\text{Cov}(X,Y)/\text{Var}(X) = \rho \sigma_y/\sigma_x$ can be made smaller or larger by choosing different units for $x$ or $y$ (e.g. going from dollars to cents or meters to millimeters or vice-versa).

As a result, I think you can do it simply by changing units.

Comment: (+1) Good point. In my case both $X$ and $Y$ are necessarily and inherently measured in the same units - I cannot change that.

Comment: That's kind of an important restriction, wouldn't you think? It should probably appear in your question.

Comment: Even in the same units, if for some reason $\sigma_x$ is much smaller than $\sigma_y$, that ratio might be large.

Comment: Yes, it can happen of course. I am "fishing" for real world experience, "I have seen it happen", "now that you mention it I always found covariance to be smaller than both variances", or "working with XXX data I did found covariance to be in between the two variances"... things like that.

Comment: Personal anecdotes don't necessarily generalize to your specific unstated circumstances. I wouldn't have any basis on which to guess what the ratio of $\sigma$'s would be in your application, let alone the $\rho$.

Comment: No, but it is gathered evidence in any case. I am not looking to formally generalize here -as I said, this is not tied to any specific "part of the world".

Comment: I wish I could be more help on this. I don't know on what basis one could generalize to "likely in practice". The question as it stands now seems to be both impossibly broad, and relying essentially on personal opinion. What goes in the denominator of some probability assessment of 'likely'?

Comment: "Likely to observe or not" is my burden. From the people here I only ask for any related experience with real-world data sets. I don't think this is broad.

Comment: I am with Glen_b on this. In general, covariance and variance don't have the same dimensions or units of measurement. So your inequality is at worst meaningless and at best entirely dependent on conventions about choice of unit. I can't see a genuine problem here.

Comment: @NickCox If $X$ and $Y$ are measured in the same units, then covariance and variance have the same dimensions and the same units of measurement. And at least in econometrics, we have all the time variables measured in the same units and being present in the same relation.

Comment: That assumption should in my view appear in the very first sentence of your question.

Answer (score 4):

The `trees` data from the R `datasets` package:

> This data set provides measurements of the girth, height and volume of
>   timber in 31 felled black cherry trees.  Note that girth is the
>   diameter of the tree (in inches) measured at 4 ft 6 in above the
>   ground.

The correlation between girth & height is $0.52$, while the ratio of the standard deviations of girth to height is only $\frac{3.14''}{76.4''}=0.04$.

It's rather common to measure correlations between measurements of large magnitude to measurements of small magnitude with roughly similar coefficients of variation, & there's no particular reason such correlations should be small.

Note that if girth were expressed as circumference rather than diameter the ratio of standard deviations would be 0.13; in fact some queer way of expressing the observations might always be found to raise the value of the ratio over that of the correlation. So the question's about not just what's likely to be observed, but what's likely to be written down.

Comment: To be honest I'm baffled as to why anyone might think it unusual.